# How to Join multiple tables in PHALCON FRAMEWORK

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I am trying to join two tables(MYSQL) in **Phalcon framework**.

"**Table**" names:

```
user
contact_details
```

"**Model**" names:

```
User
ContactDetails
```

**Initialize**:

```
In "User" model ----->$this->hasMany("id", "ContactDetails", "user_id"); 
In "ContactDetails" model----->$this->belongsTo("user_id", "User", "id");
```

**My code**:

```
public function userDetails(){             
      $phql = "SELECT User.*, ContactDetails.* FROM User LEFT JOIN ContactDetails";
      $user = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
      -------
      -------Remaining code---------
      --------------
      }
Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the quick reply.

I actually need to run an MySQL query instead of using built-in functions.

Here is the fix which I finally got:

```
$query = "SELECT u.*, c.* FROM user u "
              . "LEFT JOIN ContactDetails c "
              . "ON c.user_id = u.id ORDER BY u.id ";
      $cars = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($query);
      $user = array();      
      foreach ($cars as $car) {
        //print_r($car);exit;
          $user[$car->u->id]['firstname'] = $car->u->firstname;
          $user[$car->u->id]['lastname'] = $car->u->lastname;
          $user[$car->u->id]['username'] = $car->u->username;
          $user[$car->u->id]['emailid'] = $car->u->emailid;
          $user[$car->u->id]['address'] = $car->c->address;
          $user[$car->u->id]['street'] = $car->c->street;
          $user[$car->u->id]['city'] = $car->c->city;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested but it might give you the idea, you don't actually need to use $phql as the model should hold everything you need.

```
$users = User::find();

foreach($users as $user) {
    // whatever you want
    echo $user->name;

    foreach($user->contactdetails as $contactDetails) {
        echo $contactDetails->telephone;
    }
}
```

You can get all this information from the docs - http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html